# What to do with the results of extended Euclidean algorithm

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption

I am currently working on an essay about public key encryption, RSA specifically. 
I understand most of the algorithms involved in generation of public and private keys. But I am struggling to understand what do I do with Bézout's identity to get private key? And also I dont quite understand why Bézout's identity is used at all?

Assume that:

```
n=55
phi(n)=40    
e = 7
```

So that e*d mod phi(n) = 1

```
7*d mod 40 = 1
gcd(40,7) = 1
```

And so that Bézout's identity looks like this:

```
3(40)-17(7)=1
```

Where 40 and 7 are phi(n) and e respectively.

I know from example that d should be 23.
So am I right that d = e - 17?

If not how do I get d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `d = -17` (since Bézout's identity says that there exist `x` and `y` such that `x*a + y*b = gcd(a,b)`).

You are looking for a `d` such that `e*d = 1 mod phi(n)`, so you can convert this negative `d` into a positive value that still satisfies the equation by simply adding a multiple of `phi(n)`. In this case we just need to add `phi(n)` once, which gives your expected value for `d`:

```
-17 + phi(n) = -17 + 40 = 23
```

Comment: Thanks, clarified why it is like that